# How to await loading data before mapping?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm trying to map some data that I have stored in an array (the screenshot below), but I can't seem to access it, because it is loaded asynchronously. How could I await the data? Is there a way to do it in the render function?

```
      render() {
         
        return (
          {this.state.serials.map((number) => {
    return number.s && number.s.length? 
    (
        <h2 > {number.s[0].a}</h2>
  ) : null
})}
        )
    }
```

This is componentDidMount() where I get my data:

```
      componentDidMount() 
        const uid = this.state.user.uid;
        const gatewayRef = db.ref(uid + '/gateways');
        gatewayRef.on('value', (gateways_nums) => {
            const serialsArr = [];
          gateways_nums.forEach((gateway_num) => {
            const serialRef = db.ref('gateways/' + gateway_num.val()['gateway'])
            const last_temps =[];
            serialRef.on('value', (serials)=>{ 
                const ser = []
                serials.forEach((serial)=>{
                    ser.push(serial.val()['serial'])
                })
                last_temps.push({a: gateway_num.val()['gateway'], b: ser})
            })
            serialsArr.push({s:last_temps})
          });
          this.setState({serials:serialsArr})
        });
      }
```

I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: share sample data array as Text so other can test code and can help you

Comment: The console log of `⏷[]`, near the bottom of your screenshot, suggests that the content is retrieved asynchronously and your code might run before it is loaded.

Comment: @trincot I think there shouldn't be a problem with it running asynchronously. I opened the array just to show what kind of data I have. The data is added to that array in the componentDidMount() and I use a similar function elsewhere and it works fine.

Comment: I'm just saying what I see. If you think it's not a problem, I wonder how you explain that part of the screen shot. Any way, if you want help, then make sure we can reproduce the issue. BTW, if you want to be absolutely sure what the content is *at the time of logging*, then convert it to JSON, with `JSON.stringify` and log that.

Comment: Can you provide the data which is stored in `this.state.serials` in text format (not an image)

Comment: If the data is really like you depicted it *at the moment* the code runs, then the code works as expected. I repeat my suspicion that the data is not populated yet when your code runs, and you are mislead by what the console shows you (which is lazy and may show data that is loaded later).

Comment: @trincot Thank you very much for your help! You were probably right - it logs this: [{"s":[]},{"s":[]},{"s":[]},{"s":[]}] with JSON-stringified.

Comment: @trincot yeah agree with you, data may come after this code was executed. because i ran code and its work fine

Comment: So if you now still have a question about this, and don't know how you can await the loading of the data before running this `.map`, then revise your question to focus on the asynchronous code that loads the data.